# Is this variant of multiset covering problem NP-hard?

Tags: np-complete, np-hard, sets, subset-sum

Consider this variant of multiset covering problem.

Input: a collection of sets $S = \{s_1, s_2, \ldots, s_n\}$  and a universal set $U$, in which $s_k \subseteq U$ and $s_k \neq \emptyset$ for all $k$.

The problem is, given an non-empty multiset $M$ containing elements from $U$, we are allowed to pick at most one element from each set in $S$ to form a new multiset $P$. We need $P$ to cover $M$ as many times as possible. For $P$ to cover $M$ $n$ times means for each element in $M$, there are at least $n$ copies in $P$.

For example, if $S = \{\{1, 2, 3\}, \{2, 3\}, \{2\}, \{2\}, \{1\}, \{1\}, \{1, 3\}\}$ and $M = \{1, 1, 2\}$, we should be able to form $P = \{1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1\}$ by picking 1 element from the 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 5th, 6th and 7th sets respectively. This will cover $M$ 2 times. (To cover $M$ 3 times will require six $1$s and three $2$s, which is impossible from just 7 sets)

Is the above problem NP-Hard?

Answer (score 1):

This is a matching problem and can therefore be solved efficiently.

Make a bipartite graph where one side is $S$, and the other side is $B$, made up of $n$ copies of $M$. If you enumerate the elements of $M$, $m_1,\ldots,m_k$, then $b_{i,j}\in B = m_j$ for all $i\in [n]$. Then draw an edge from $s_\ell$ to $b_{i,j}$ iff $m_j\in s_\ell$ for all $i,j,\ell$. Now it's easy to see that you can cover $M$ $n$ times iff there is a matching in the graph with $|B|$ edges. Trying with different sizes of $n$, you can find the greatest one.

There is probably a more efficient way to find a matching that saturates one side $n$ times (such that you only need one copy of $M$), but this at least shows that the problem is not NP-hard (unless P=NP, of course).